# How to send a value to parent component from child component based on condition?

Tags: angular

It's not working and showing the error type boolean is not assignable to type `value?: boolean`.
       Also, I want the value of registered to be initially false. Can we initialize it in output? Currently, it's `undefined` initially.
       When the user registers successfully on submit then registered should change to true in register component and its value should go to the parent component

**child.component.ts (Child)**

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() registered: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    onSubmit() {
    this.reg.registerUser(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
          (res) => {
              this.registered.emit = res ? true : false;
              ....
              ....
             }
```

**home.component.ts (Parent)**

```
 <app-register (registered)="doSomething($event)"></app-register>
```

Comment: `this.registered.emit(res ? true : false)`

Comment: Or just `this.registered.emit(!!res)` or `this.registered.emit(Boolean(res))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `emit()` is a method so you need call method like below

```ts
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() registered: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    onSubmit() {
    this.reg.registerUser(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
          (res) => {
              let isRegistered = res ? true : false;
              this.registered.emit(isRegistered);
              ....
              ....
         }
 }
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can emit false in ngOnInit-

```ts
ngOnInit(){
 this.registered.emit (false);
}
```

And change the code like this-

```ts
this.registered.emit ( res ? true : false);
```